# Image Recognition Benchmarks

Tags: algorithms

I was wondering if anyone knew anywhere I can obtain benchmark comparison of various algorithms used for similarity recognition. In my research I found one study from 2008 or so, but misplaced the URL.

Comment: It depends on type/kind of images your're trying to compare. Is it textures/random fields/faces/etc?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. It's just general images, similar to Tineye or "google search by image"